# Automatic web browsing for windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, automation

There's a website (telephonic company) where I get a statistic information about the amount of data transferred by my phone during the current month.
To access that information, I need:
* Access the website and login with username and passwod (html form)
* Then choose an option in a combo box (html select)
* And finally click on a link that shows the information (html a)

I want to develop an app that does all this process automatically, and shows only the statistic data.
There's a way to do this in C#?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm begginer with C# and WP7. An example would be appreciated :)

Comment: @ben.qiao, Please edit post instead of posting another answer

Answer (score 1):

Please read [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser_methods%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). Method `InvokeScript(String, String[])` may be useful. try to use javascript complete above, if a website page inclued those "login,html selec,submit..."  is all the better.